# Inner join in python-django framework

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have 2 models.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

class Address(models.Model):
    add_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_address = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "address"
```

I have one SQL query

```
select u.*,a.user_address from users u inner join address a on a.user_id = u.user_id;
```

I want to implement this query using django models.
I'm new to Django framework.

I'm trying below query, but it's not returning correct output.

```
user = User.objects.filter(user_id__in=Address.objects.values_list('user_id'))
```

Comment: Are you working with a legacy database or is this a new project? Why have you not used a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for the `Address.user_id` field?

Comment: It's legacy database. can you tell how i can perform inner join with existing database? or i have to make foreign key Address.user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your models, you can make `user` a foreign key, without having to change the database schema.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    add_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKeyCharField(max_length=30)
    ...
```

If you have an `address` instance, you can then access the `user` with `address.user`, and the `user_id` with `address.user_id`.

If you have a queryset of addresses, you can then use `select_related()` to make Django join to the user table.

```
addresses = Address.objects.all().select_related('user')
for address in address:
    # access a field on the address model
    print(address.user_address)
    # access a field on the user model through the foreign key
    print(address.user.user_name)
```